# Localhost page cannot be found using node-static

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, node-static

I am trying to serve static files using node-static. Later I intend to run this as Windows service using nssm. I have run this before but don't know why, it doesn't work now.

Below is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var nStatic = require('node-static');

var fileServer = new nStatic.Server(); ---> I also tried new nStatic.Server('filepath')
//setting middleware

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
        fileServer.serve(req, res);
}).listen(9000);
```

I start the server using node server.js on command prompt. This is what I see

http://localhost:9000:
[image: http://localhost:9000]

Node -v 10.15.2
NPM -v 6.4.1

Comment: pic shown your server didn't started

Comment: So I edited my code to - 

var http = require('http');

var nStatic = require('node-static');

var fileServer = new nStatic.Server(); ---> I also tried new nStatic.Server('filepath')
//setting middleware

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
        console.log("ServerStarted");
        fileServer.serve(req, res);
}).listen(9000);

and now on starting the server and navigating to http://localhost:9000 I see the Server Started message on command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the full path until the folder to see the contents of it which now seems obvious as I localhost:9000 was never a file.

I used something like this - http://localhost:9000/Test/test.txt